# whether "have" is a main verb or not

Tags: verbs

> People there may **have** to go hungry.

In the sentence, I'd like to know whether "have" is a main verb or not. If it is a main verb, is the meaning of it "experience or feel"?

Comment: 'Have to' isn't a main verb; it's an auxiliary verb used with the infinitive of a verb when you need to, be forced to, or must do something.

Answer (score 1):

"To have to do" is a substitute form for must. As "to have to do" is a shortened version of "to have the obligation to do" I would say "to have" in this use is a normal verb.

"to have" is an auxiliary verb in the perfect tenses.

Your sentence means: It is possible that people have to go hungry/must go hungry. "to go hungry" is an idiomatic expression for a lacking verb; English has no verb like to hunger. (In German there is such a verb: Jetzt müssen wir hungern.)

You can paraphrase "to go hungry" by "to feel hungry" or "to suffer from hunger".